# Estado HTTP 500 Objetivo inalcanzable, identificador resuelto a nulo JSF

Tags: jsf

After running the Web project in JSF the following error is presented in the backing bean: `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException
Objetivo inalcanzable, identificador`

Comment: Suggestion: change your development environment to English. There are MANY more useful results when you search on an English error message.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of errors appear because of the wrong importing of frameworks.

Solution: You must use `import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;` instead of import javax.annotation.ManagedBean.